# How to show pop-up then user close page use js

Tags: javascript

I have broblem.

Situation - user **first time** visited in site. User want **close** page (not go anover page, only close). Site have pop up comprising offer discounts.

I need show pop up befor user left site.

Comment: [window onunload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)

Comment: i try this function, but i cant show my popup, only standart alert. And this event start than user navigate in site.

Answer (score 1):

Use onbeforeunload method.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Your message here.';
};
```

Comment: I try this function, but i cant show my popup. And not all browser support custom message.

Comment: This is the only method that works on modern browsers.  The other stuff was used and abused to create popups, pop-unders, reopening the closed page and other nasty things.